# React-router - component reloads on parent component state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, state, material-ui

In my React app, I have a ResponsiveDrawer component taken from [material-ui's demo](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/drawers/#responsive-drawer). It's basically just a React component which renders a drawer with a list of menu items, a title bar and content frame.

It has `mobileOpen` in its state

```
state = {
    mobileOpen: false
};
```

which changes when user clicks the hamburger icon

```
handleDrawerToggle = () => {
    this.setState({ mobileOpen: !this.state.mobileOpen });
};

(...)

<Drawer type="temporary" anchor="left" open={this.state.mobileOpen} classes={{paper: classes.drawerPaper}} onRequestClose={this.handleDrawerToggle} ModalProps={{keepMounted: true // Better open performance on mobile.}}>
    <div>
        <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
        <Divider />
        <MenuList onRequestClose={this.handleDrawerToggle} />
    </div>
```

I also have set up some routes inside the content of the ResponsiveDrawer:

```
<main className={classes.content}>
    <div className={classes.contentWrapper}>
        <Switch>
            <Route
                exact
                path="/currencies"
                component={CurrenciesComponent}
            />
            <Route
                exact
                path="/"
                component={ProfileComponent}
            />
            <Route component={NotFoundComponent} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
</main>
```

CurrenciesComponent from the route is defined as follows:

```
const CurrenciesComponent = () => (
        <Currencies isSignedIn={this.isSignedIn} />
    );
```

When I click the hamburger icon, the state of ResponsiveDrawer changes, however the CurrenciesComponent is also reloaded (I have an API call there which takes a few seconds to complete so I would like to avoid this).

If I define my route as follows (without passing the props to Currencies component), this doesn't happen:

```
<Route exact path="/currencies" component={Currencies} />
```

So how do I avoid the re-render and provide props to Currencies at the same time when specifying the route?

Answer (score 4):

I solved the issue by using `render` instead of `component` prop for my routes:

```
<Route exact path="/currencies" render={CurrenciesComponent}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tell your component if it should update.

As part of React's lifecycle, each component has the method [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) that gets run each time it gets a signal to update. Returning true from this function will tell the component to update and false will tell it not to.

Since all you're doing is asking it not to render if the props remain the same, you may be able to use [PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) instead of Component. PureComponent implements `shouldComponentUpdate` and doesn't update unless props or state has changed.

Comment: I don't think this has to do with the lifecycle of the child component. The reason being, the constructor of Currencies component is called in my first example. So it will update regardless of shouldComponentUpdate.

Comment: The constructor is called twice? Once on load and once when opening the drawer?

Comment: Exactly, but this happens only if I pass a function to route's component prop like so `<Route
                                    exact
                                    path="/currencies"
                                    component={() => (
            <Currencies />
        )}`